Observations of NetCDF variable are all masked
I am completely new to NetCDF4 dataset and I am trying to figure out how to extract the relevant variable I am interest to
I think I have managed to correctly download and import the data in python. This is the structure of the data
df = nc.Dataset(path, "r")
print(df)

This is the structure of the data:
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>
root group (NETCDF3_CLASSIC data model, file format NETCDF3):
    Conventions: CF-1.6
    contacts: copernicus-support@ecmwf.int
    contract: C3S Demo Case Soil Erosion
    title: Soil erosion indicators for Italy from 1981 to 2080
    institution: Fondazione Centro Euro-Mediterraneo sui Cambiamenti Climatici (CMCC)
    author: Dr. Monia Santini; monia.santini@cmcc.it
    version: version 1.0
    dimensions(sizes): time(1), bnds(2), lon(2764), lat(2389)
    variables(dimensions): float64 time(time), float64 time_bnds(time, bnds), float64 lon(lon), float64 lat(lat), float64 rf(time, lat, lon)
    groups: 

When I type the following code to see the content of the variable "rf", this is what I get:
df.variables['rf'][:]
masked_array(
  data=[[[--, --, --, ..., --, --, --],
         [--, --, --, ..., --, --, --],
         [--, --, --, ..., --, --, --],
         ...,
         [--, --, --, ..., --, --, --],
         [--, --, --, ..., --, --, --],
         [--, --, --, ..., --, --, --]]],
  mask=[[[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
         ...,
         [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]]],
  fill_value=nan)


and when I ask Python whether the whole column is masked this is what I get:
df.variables['rf'].mask
True

What does it mean? I think this procedure is quite straightforward and I don't see what is wrong here.
EDIT
I did some further research and it seems the problem could be linked to some sample dimension. If I explore the content of:
rf = df.variables['rf']

There are two "min" and "max" string object with the following warning:
'ndarray too big, calculating max would slow down debugging'

I have therefore tried to shrink a bit the amount of desired observations in the following way:
min_lat = 45  
max_lat = 46
min_lon = 10  
max_lon = 11

lat_var = df.variables['lat'][:]
lon_var = df.variables['lon'][:]

lat_indices = np.where((lat_var >= min_lat) & (lat_var <= max_lat))[0]
lon_indices = np.where((lon_var >= min_lon) & (lon_var <= max_lon))[0]

rf_data = df.variables['rf'][:, lat_indices, lon_indices]

Finally, I can see some "non masked" observations. I now have to find a clever way to extract all the observations, do you have some hints?
